# Netbeans doesn't like dots on my decimals

Tags: java, netbeans

I'm supposed to create a simple program in Java that will take a value for a price and another for a discount. The price must be float and the discount must be int. I managed to create the program well enough to apply the discount properly.

To further on my problem here's my code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Ex_g {

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner dados = new Scanner(System.in);
        float preco;
        int desconto;

       // System.out.println("preco?");
        do {
        preco = dados.nextFloat();   
        } while (preco > 1000.00);

       // System.out.println("desconto?");
        do {
        desconto = dados.nextInt();   
        } while ( (desconto < 0) && (desconto > 100));


        float res = (float)preco - (preco * desconto/100);
        System.out.printf("%.2f\n", res);
    }

}
```

It is nothing complicated but the problem resides on how it takes the values, I'm supposed to enter the price as "500.00" for example, yet the program only takes "500,00" difference being it needs a comma.

I am aware that netbeans (I'm using netbeans) does this kind of thing but what made me come here and write this post is the fact that the values are printed with commas (,) too instead of dots ( . ) and thus the platform I'm sending this code to considers the exercise to be wrong...

I'll be trying another compiler but at the same time I'd like to hear someone's opinion on why I can't enter decimal values separated by a dot. And if possible, how can I fix it.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This is not about your ide. It is about locales. You want to Google that term to understand how the JVM is parsing numbers, well based on the locale you are running with.

Comment: Try adding an "f" to the end of your "500.00" to specify that your value is a float.